# Block website only to be accessible from cloudflare

Tags: web, hosting, cloudflare

I have my domains and DNS in Cloudflare but have multiple website in local & other hosting providers.
Currently i am using port forwarding in the hosting side and DNS in routed to public at Cloudflare.

My problem is some security settings i have defined in Cloudflare but the host is accessible with ip address, which by passes the Cloudflare settings.

How can i prevent this, how can i open the ports only to be accessible though Cloudflare DNS.

Regards
Ibbe

Website should be accessible only from dns. I want to accept only HTTPs

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your DNS records in Cloudflare as a "Proxied", and in the  "local & other hosting providers" you should allow access only from Cloudflare ip addresses. You can found the IP ranges here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/